# How to do a partial update an object in Golang using GORM?

Tags: sql, go, backend, go-gorm

I have the following struct:

```golang
type Shop struct {
    ID          uint32    `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment" json:"id"`
    Name        string    `gorm:"size:255;not null;unique" json:"name"`
    Email       string    `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"email"`
    PhoneNumber string    `gorm:"size:50;unique" json:"phone_number"`
    Password    string    `gorm:"size:100;not null;" json:"password"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
}
```

And I am having the following function for my struct in order to update the object in the database; which is working fine when every field is passed:

```golang
func (shop *Shop) UpdateAShop(db *gorm.DB, uid uint32) (*Shop, error) {

    // To hash the password
    err := shop.BeforeSave()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    db = db.Debug().Model(&Shop{}).Where("id = ?", uid).Take(&Shop{}).Updates(
        map[string]interface{}{
            "password":     shop.Password,
            "name":         shop.Name,
            "phone_number": shop.PhoneNumber,
            "email":        shop.Email,
            "update_at":    time.Now(),
        },
    )
    if db.Error != nil {
        print("database error")
        return &Shop{}, db.Error
    }
    // This is the display the updated shop
    err = db.Debug().Model(&Shop{}).Where("id = ?", uid).Take(&shop).Error
    if err != nil {
        return &Shop{}, err
    }
    return shop, nil
}
```

But, if I want to do a partial update using a PATCH HTTP request, it doesn't work and result in the following error:

```json
{
    "error": "Incorrect Details"
}
```

The data that I'm trying to pass is something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "My Shop"
}
```

I have gone through GORM documentation and I couldn't find something about partial updates (Maybe I am not looking at the right part of the documentation) and I have searched through the internet and did not found something concise. How would I be able to do it?

Comment: If you want to update only selective fields, then you can use `Select("col1", "col2").Updates` to just update 2 columns. See the documentation [page](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Update-Selected-Fields)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran is correct or you can create a map with just the fields you want to update.